# override lazy val in constructor / scala

Tags: scala

I want to override a lazy val in the constructor in scala. Any ideas how to do this ? I tried the following but i get

> 'lazy' modifier not allowed here, use call-by-name parameter instead

```
  class Dog(override lazy val creatureType: String) extends Animal {

// valid
//  override lazy val creatureType: String = "Dog"
// but i want to override it in the constructor directly 

}
```

The Parent class :

```
  class Animal {
 lazy val creatureType: String = "unknown"
  }
```

Comment: `class Dog(creatureType: String) extends Animal` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
   class Dog(foo: => String) extends Animal {
     override lazy val creatureType = foo
   }
```

Comment: what's the difference between ( foo: => String) and ( foo : String ) . Doesn't the latter work too ?

Comment: @Helix112 `foo: String` works, but it would not be lazy. This is called [by name parameter](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/by-name-parameters.html)